# With Visual Studio, is it possible to lock solution so build is not available?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I would like to prevent a solution (.sln) file to be build so any project(s) and their outputs cannot be updated. Is this something that is possible to do?

Comment: Why? What's the real problem?

Comment: There are post-build step that is possible to deploy the end result output to wrong location. While development it is fine to update it as much as possible, but someone could forget to update in the next version.